# Making a late application for residency as an EU citizen

Tags: residency, italy

I have been living in Italy since spring 2015 and working since summer 2016.

Due to regular trips to my home country, I have not applied for Italian residency (until recently I believed it was primarily for access to healthcare).

My current understanding is that after moving here I should have applied for residence after 90 days. Could I face any repercussions if I apply now, after already having lived here for two years?

Comment: Yes, but the repercussions must be proportional (similar to those an Italian would encounter for failing to register after moving to Italy from abroad).  I don't know what the situation is in Italy, but in the UK there's no penalty because there's no registration requirement for British citizens, and in France the penalty is that the cost of the application rises from €25 to €340.